# How to raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if not all records are found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given that item with id of 1 exists in the database, but item with id of 2 does not, the following line:

```
Item.find([1, 2])
```

will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error. However, the following line will not:

```
Item.where(id: [1, 2])
```

Instead, it will just return the item with id of 1. Is there a way to enforce the behavior of `find` on `where` if I am querying on unique values.

I have a model `Foo`, which, apart from an `id`, also has a `uid` string attribute. Each `foo` has a unique `uid` value. So given an array of `uids`, I'd like to be able to either fetch all the `foos` or raise an error, if for one of the `uid` values a `foo` doesn't exist.

P.S. I could do something like `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless query_result.count == uids.count`, but I want to know, if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there isnt any such provision with `where`(which just returns a relation instead of the actual AR objects).

I checked the source code and it looks like `ActiveRecord` uses the same trick to raise `RecordNotFound` exception with find when it cant find a certain id from the array passed. (match the size of the results against the size of the ids array passed)
Referred the method `find` calls [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c910fd82dcbb89799d21dcb60da5c1b5de48f5fc/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L474) and the place where they raise the exception [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c910fd82dcbb89799d21dcb60da5c1b5de48f5fc/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L491)

Comment: Thank you, @alok-swain, I tried to find the place in the source as well, but wasn't able to track the execution chain. This really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Here if you want to raise an  `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.
you have to use `ActiveRecord#find` method because `ActiveRecord#where` does not raise this error.

I think you  should use `ActiveRecord#find` but you can do try

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
foo = Foo.where(id: ids)
a = foo.pluck(:id)
raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if ids!=a
```

Comment: I think you could just `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound foo.size < ids.size`

Comment: @ankur-pohekar `find` only works with ids and I'm querying on an attribute, that is also unique like the id, but is not a primary key. Hence, I can only use `where`.